# Pages in my website has both http and https, how to solve it having only https?

Tags: .htaccess, https, http

I have a problem with HTTP redirect:

I start and say that my homepage redirects perfectly HTTP to HTTPS. All my pages are showing HTTPS as well, but once I put the URL with HTTP, or with just `www.example.co.uk/page1` it will go to the HTTP one.

For example:

```
https://example.co.uk/about-us/

http://example.co.uk/about-us/
```

I already had this code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?example.co.uk
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and I've changed it to code I saw someone mentioned to fix the problem:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and it still not working, both have the same issue.

**Edit#1:** I have another code above the one I mentioned, it was there since always:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
</IfModule>
```

**Edit#2:** My complete `.htaccess` file:

[image: Complete .htaccess file]

Comment: Do you have any other code in your `.htaccess` file? It looks like you might have put the code in the wrong place - the order of these directives is important.

Comment: Yes, i do have above that code, another code which was already exist since always, unfortunately i cant add here the code (it just added here as a text, not sure why) could you please check my post again> i've edited and added the other code. much appreciate that!

Comment: Have you checked in incognito mode if the issue exists? Browser might have a cached copy of the page which it is showing.

Comment: Hi Tero, yeas actually im always checking any changes through incognito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have another code above the one i mentioned

You've put the code in the wrong place. Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect needs to go *before* the existing code, at the very top of your `.htaccess` file.

By placing your redirect after the above code, it's not going to get processed for anything other than the homepage (root directory), or existing files/directories. Hence why you are only seeing the redirect for the homepage.

You don't need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.

You also have a superfluous `RewriteCond` directive at the end that should be removed.

In other words, your `.htaccess` should look like this:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Front-controller
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Although, unless this is WordPress and you also have `# BEGIN WordPress` / `# END WordPress` comment markers, then the `<IfModule>` wrapper is unnecessary and would be more readable if rewritten like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Front-controller
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Note that I removed the slash prefix on the last `RewriteRule` *substitution* string. (This is what the `RewriteBase` directive is for. Although the `RewriteBase` directive is not strictly necessary here.)

Comment: Hi again MrWhite, thanks for the detailed answer! just to make sure - it is a WordPress site (sorry i haven't mention that) - i see in the htaccess file a note that i shouldn't remove the line which is the code that located below the first code,  can you please check the image i've attached in the post?

Comment: In your first example you start the RewriteEngine after you have already used it. ;)

Comment: ok i've just copied and pasted what @MrWhite mentioned and its now working perfect! thanks you so much for your help, you saved me!

Comment: @Ronchos_ Keep the comment markers intact and move the complete code block (including the `RewriteEngine` directive) - it looks like that code might be maintained by a plugin? (If it's not maintained by a plugin then you don't need the comment markers, or additional `RewriteEngine` directive.)

Comment: @EsaJokinen Yes, that's OK - the `RewriteEngine` directive is not processed in order. (I'd only suggest doing it like that with WordPress, where you are advised not to edit between the `# BEGIN` comment markers, so need to leave the original `RewriteEngine On` directive in place.) If you have multiple `RewriteEngine` directives then the _last_ instance wins and controls the entire file - so if you have `RewriteEngine` directives earlier in the file then they aren't actually doing anything and are arguably misleading (since setting an earlier `RewriteEngine` to `Off` will have no effect).

Comment: Thanks, good explanation!